# integral question substitution

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

$∫ \dfrac{g(x)g'(x)}{\sqrt{(1+g^2(x))}}$  where $g'(x)$ is continous.  I tried use use substitution but I couldn't figure out which one to substitute.

Comment: Try substituting $u=g(x)$ to make it more readable. Then try $v = 1+u^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am attaching the solution of the pic. and go through it. Although you got enough hint.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$g(x)=t$, then you get

$\int \frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}}dt=\sqrt{1+t^{2}}+C$,

so

$\int \frac{g(x)g'(x)}{\sqrt{1+g(x)^{2}}}dx=\sqrt{1+g(x)^{2}}+C$